# Is it a bad practice to design an HTML layout with all elements with position absolute?

Tags: html, css, position

There is a framework that my company wants to acquire that generates all HTML with position absolute. It has its own GUI Designer. Mainly this application will be used to design HTML forms. Is it a bad practice to have a complete HTML layout with position absolute? I am afraid that this will be a maintenance hell in the long run.

**EDIT**:

They claim that it is a responsive design and that it can be used across multiple devices. I'm skeptic about this.

Comment: Depends on the purpose of the projects you'll make with it. If you decide you want it to work responsively across multiple devices then yes, it will be a problem. If it's a kiosk application where all devices are exactly the same size then no, you won't have so many issues (in fact it'll probably make testing a bit easier).

Comment: Can you provide a link to this framework?

Comment: @Luke it is a closed framework. I don't even have it but they showed us a presentation of how they create the HTML. They use a GUI designer, that GUI designer generates an XML with a specific format, then something parses that XML and generates the HTML.  The problem is that everything generated in the XML has "x" and "y" position which it is rendered as a position absolute in HTML.

Comment: The question is about implementation and not UX - I suggest it to be migrated to stackoverflow, where you shall get much more informed answers.

Comment: IMO I think "closed framework" is much worse than how things are positioned.

Comment: @Izhaki it is not about implementation. It is about user interface design choice. Should you use or not position absolute for everything in an HTML?

Comment: @Izhaki changed the title to make it clear.

Comment: Alfredo, I'm afraid html (or css) positioning is not something you learn in UX schools - the UXer will create a wireframe showing where different elements go, whether this is realised by relative or absolute positioning is in the hand of the developers. Unless I've completely misunderstood your question - users won't be affected by whether stuff is absolute or not.

Comment: What is static positioning and how is it different from absolute? Did you mean 'relative'?

Comment: @Izhaki good point, feel free to migrate it if you think this should be in SackOverflow. Thanks.

Comment: This question would probably end up getting locked on SO for being subjective or too broad.  Maybe Programmers SE would be a better spot?

Comment: Yes, it's a bad practice. Run away from this product.

Comment: To be fair, HOW a page is constructed DOES affect the UX. A good UX team should be cognizant of that--even if they themselves aren't the ones coding it.

Comment: XML!!! Stay clear.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read other peoples answers, because I'm pretty sure everybody is saying "bad practice". I just watched this talk this last weekend, and this guys are off the hook, but work ever and believe it or not, they do everything absolute: http://vimeo.com/61252376

Answer (score 3):

I would say that although it may not be the worst sin in the world, it is probably bad practice. One problem: If you have everything positioned absolutely and the window re-sizes, the page will probably have to run some javascript to resize the elements.

Answer (score 1):

I use absolute positioning quite a bit as a replacement to floats (in some cases) because it works very well for me for responsive design purposes. I never position anything absolutely unless it is relative to something else.

So for example, in the header for my website, at the far left I want a logo, at the far right I want a menu button. What I do is create a div for the header, assign it relative positioning, then place my images inside the div with absolute positioning. The logo has `left: 0%` and menu has `right: 0%`. The header div adjusts its width based on the browser size, but no matter what the width, my two elements are always at opposite ends. Works great for responsive purposes, for me anyway. I'm sure there are other solutions.

Of course, this is one example. I use the same sort of technique all over the place (i.e. "relatively absolute positioning", as I call it).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say without seeing the page and its markup. There may be a reason for it but ... not likely. Some people use absolute positioning for everything because it's easier, and it may well be the best solution for whatever this is, but, as one who does this all the time, I'm questioning whether it's actually necessary. And that brings me around to the beginning of this. There is no way to know without seeing it.